# How to solve a function acting differently based on callsite?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, glfw

Not sure how to word the title so feel free to rename, but the issue I'm having is that I've got a function that works in one project, but fails in another. Below is rough pseudocode to show that one call in LibraryProject works, whereas the call in GameProject doesn't.

In `ChildClass::do_stuff`, the win32_window HWND is valid,  whereas the second one, `failed_win32_window` is null and glfw throws an error saying it isn't initialized, despite it already having been initialized (since the first glfw call was successful and I've manually stepped through to verify it was):

```
GLFWError #65537 Happen, The GLFW library is not initialized
```

---

Here's pseudocode showing the two projects, and the files. GLFW is set initialized properly since if I do all my glfw logic within LibraryProject, the window shows up as normal.

```
//LibraryProject

////library_header.h
class ParentClass {
  GLFW* _mainWindow; //filled in elsewhere in the real code
  HWND getWin32Window() { return glfwGetWin32Window(_mainWindow); }
}

//GameProject

////game_header.h
#include "library_header.h" //from other Project

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
  void do_stuff() {
    HWND win32_window = this->getWin32Window(); //this works because it goes down into LibraryProject.dll's module
    HWND failed_win32_window = glfwGetWin32Window(_mainWindow); //but literally the same call here doesn't because it happens within GameProject.exe
  }
}

////game_body.cpp

void function_called_elsewhere_in_game() {
    //called from GameProject.exe
    auto child = ChildClass();
    child.do_stuff();
}
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with glfw and my setup, or just my misunderstanding how projects and dependencies work.

Things I've tried:

- Downloading the latest [glfw3](https://www.glfw.org/download.html)
- Rebuilding the entire solution
- Toggling with References and Linking Dependency Inputs

Things to note:

- This is happening in the main thread, nothing else is using glfw at the same time. Its 100% reproducible too.
- `glfw3.lib` is always being created in my GameProject output folder, based on the one inside LibraryProject
- Stepping through the disassembly for each of the two `glfwGetWin32Window` calls has different addresses in disassembly, leading me to believe they're two different copies of the same library, but I'm not sure.
- This is not an issue with cocos2d, the game engine I'm using as starting a blank project and calling `glfwGetWin32Window(..)` returns a valid pointer, even in GameProject, so there's something that I'm doing wrong, but I don't know what.

---

Images showing off the actual behaviour. `magnolia_cocos_proj` is GameProject and is the exe I'm running, and `libcocos2d` is LibraryProject I'm using as a DLL (I'm unfamiliar with the details of how linking and dlls work).

1. [win32_window has valid value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5EFL.png)
2. [definition of getWin32Window() to be 100% sure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIKz9.png). Notice the module is in libcocos2d.dll now.
3. [after going over the second line, the error throws and the second window is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H6Bn.png)

Comment: Is your application multithread? From glfw docs: _Most GLFW functions must only be called from the main thread (the thread that calls main)_

Comment: None of these calls happen anywhere but the main thread, I'll make sure to edit the question, thanks!

Comment: The diagnostic is pretty unambiguous, it says that your program did not yet call `glfwInit()`.  No such call is visible in the snippet so that's possible.  One possible reason for this might be the usage of the name "main" for a function that does not look like the entrypoint of the program.  Bummer if the linker picked that one to get your program started.  Pick another name.  Another possible reason is that the library gets linked into the program more than once.  Could happen if LibraryProject is a DLL project, it doesn't look like one however.

Comment: @HansPassant `glfwInit()` was called within LibraryProject, I was able to verify this myself through stepping. LibraryProject is a dll project, and that dual linking then sounds like a possibility. I've updated the question to clarify some of these points

Comment: @HansPassant I was too slow to edit the first comment but thanks for the suggestions, hopefully it'll lead me to a solution!

Comment: @TankorSmash Please check your Child constructor, that it does not contain a copy of the `_mainWindow`. If you do, you might be able to access a valid version through the Parent, but this does not mean it is properly initialized in the Child. See https://godbolt.org/z/GMxiTC for an example.

Comment: @jan.sende that's a really good suggestion, but I don't have a duplicate declaration of _mainWindow, and stepping through the code, the debugger still shows the same address for `_mainWindow`, whether its in GameProject or LibraryProject

Comment: Thanks! You say the address is the same in any case... Thus, what I guess is left are: synchronization issues (if you are using multi threading), another function somehow invalidating the window, or as @ARGeo suggested, problems with different library versions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood from "`glfw3.lib` is always being created" you use static linking. Static linking of a lib to different dll and exe lead to duplicating of all static memory of the lib. You should use a dynamic library for GLFW in the case. It's `glfw3dll.lib`.

Comment: This was the answer! I swapped out a bit of the `#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3.lib")` line with the new `glfw3dll.lib`, and added the definition for `GLFW_DLL` into the projects settings, as per https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html, and everything is working great! Thanks to everyone who put forth suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

There are two main cases why this error could appear:

```
GLFWError #65537 Happen, The GLFW library is not initialised
```

***Case One*** :

The mentioned error occurs if a GLFW function was called that mustn't be called unless the library is initialised. **`So, you need to initialise GLFW before calling any function that requires initialisation`**.

Read an [API introduction](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#intro_init) for reference. Use if-else statement for handling `glfwInit()` and errors.

Reading [Moving from GLFW 2 to 3](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/moving_guide.html) is also useful.

***Case Two*** :

This error quite often occurs in the case you have previous versions of GLFW installed on your machine. GLFW3 doesn't like running along with previous version installed. **`So, delete all the GLFW libraries and linkers and reinstall the latest GLFW 3 from scratch`**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe you have not read this part of OP _GLFW is set initialized properly since if I do all my glfw logic within LibraryProject, the window shows up as normal._

Comment: Thanks for the potential answer! Like Amadeus said for Case One, the GLFW is initialized properly. For Case Two, I had gone through all the potential locations as far as I could tell for places where I'd have an extra glfw file accidentally getting included and I couldn't find one.